# Unity Jump Height Different On Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I can't figure this out. My force is put in my FixedUpdate() function and yet I'm still jumping 3 times as high on android as I am on the PC version. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Shouldn't the fixedupdate make sure it's not an fps issue? Or is it based on screen resolution?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterControllerScript : MonoBehaviour {

public KeyCode up;
public KeyCode down;

public float maxSpeed = 10f;
public bool facingRight = true;
public float tiltSpeed = 10f;
public float filter = 5.0f;
public float accelerationSpeed = 10f;
public bool jump = false;


private Vector3 accel;

Animator anim;

public bool grounded = false;
public Transform groundCheck;
float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public float jumpForce = 700;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
   anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
   accel = Input.acceleration;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

   grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
   anim.SetBool("Ground", grounded);

   anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);


   /*if (grounded && ((Input.GetKeyDown(up)) || Input.touchCount == 1)) 
     rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, Mathf.Clamp(jumpForce, 0, 700)));
   */
   if(jump){
     rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
     //rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2(0, jumpForce) * rigidbody2D.mass / Time.fixedDeltaTime);
   }

   // Set animation
   if ((Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) || (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)){
     // filter the jerky acceleration in the variable accel:
     accel = Vector3.Lerp(accel, Input.acceleration, filter * Time.deltaTime);
     // map accel -Y and X to game X and Y directions:
     Vector3 dir = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(accel.x, -accelerationSpeed, accelerationSpeed), 0, 0);
     // limit dir vector to magnitude 1:
     if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1) dir.Normalize();
     // move the object at the velocity defined in speed:
     transform.Translate(dir * tiltSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
     anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(dir.sqrMagnitude * tiltSpeed));
     if (Input.acceleration.x > 0 && !facingRight)
      Flip ();
     else if (Input.acceleration.x < 0 && facingRight)
      Flip ();
   }
   else {
     float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
     anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));
     rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

     // Decide what way animation moving
     if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
      Flip ();
     else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
      Flip ();
   }
   jump = false;
}

void Flip () {
   facingRight = !facingRight;
   Vector3 thescale = transform.localScale;
   thescale.x *= -1;
   transform.localScale = thescale;
}

void Update () {
   if(grounded && ((Input.GetKeyDown(up)) || Input.touchCount == 1)){
     anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
     //rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
     jump = true;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: well you are running different code for android then on PC, ...

Comment: yeah... how exactly are you expecting to get the same result when you do `transform.translate` on Android/Iphone, and `rigidbody2D.velocity` on everything else (including pc)?